# How to subtract large binary numbers?

Tags: r, binary, distance

I want to compare what students answered in a multiple answer test and see which students deviate by only one answer. I've already converted answers (e.g. ABCDE) into hits or misses (eg. 00101). This test has 45 questions, so answer and hits strings are very long (e.g. 100000000000000010000010010001001000000000100). Base R can't even deal with these strings as numbers because of the floating-point error.

I have `texts_1` with answers that got n questions right, and `texts_2` with answers that got n+1 questions right. Then I compare every line in `texts_1` with every line in `texts_2` to look for strings with one character of difference.

One way to do this is with `adist`.

`if (adist(texts_1[line_1], texts_2[line_2]) == 1) { ... }`

If the result is 1, I know there's only one difference in the texts. This works, but the problem is that `adist` is very slow, and I have thousand of comparisons to do. It took 4 hours to make 20000 x 30000 comparisons.

My idea was to treat the hits and misses string as a number, and subtract them. If the answer was a power of 10, I'd know there was only one question different. e.g. 1101 - 1001 is a power of 10. However, R can't deal with numbers this big. Is there a package that lets me deal with binary numbers this large? Subtract and divide? Also some binary numbers will lead with zeroes.

tl;dr: How to subtract 001111111111111101111011111111111111111111111 - 001111111111111101111011111111111110111111111 in R? And then check if the answer is a power of 10?

Comment: Two suggestions, (1) you could try integers instead of floating point numbers. (2) Instead of binary numbers, would vectors of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values work as well? Then you could apply things like `sum()` and other binary operations without the hassle of natural numbers

Comment: Use RCpp for this. And do a short circuit. Your goal is to have only one difference. If you have more than one, stop and go to the next iteration. This will be faster than pure base R functions

Answer (score 2):

A couple faster options for getting the pairwise differences.

```
library(Rfast) # for `Dist`

f1 <- function(a) {
  # from @jay.sf
  b <- strsplit(a, '') |> do.call(what='rbind') |> `mode<-`('numeric')
  dist(b, "manhattan") |> as.matrix()
}

f2 <- function(a) {
  Dist(
    matrix(utf8ToInt(paste0(a, collapse = "")), length(a), byrow = TRUE),
    "manhattan"
  )
}

f3 <- function(a) {
  n <- nchar(a[1])
  (n - crossprod(matrix(2*utf8ToInt(paste0(a, collapse = "")) - 97, n)))/2
}
```

The pairs that differ by 1 could be had by:

```
which(f3(a) == 1, TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,] 728 321
#> [2,] 841 321
#> [3,] 971 690
#> [4,] 321 728
#> [5,] 321 841
#> [6,] 989 946
#> [7,] 690 971
#> [8,] 946 989
```

Timing

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = unname(f1(a)),
  f2 = f2(a),
  f3 = f3(a),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    f1 78.7927 83.75370 88.65015 85.40460 87.88880 132.4833   100
#>    f2 63.5259 64.96575 66.80393 65.76905 67.50755  83.3841   100
#>    f3 13.0596 13.32905 15.86264 13.67160 17.24970  58.8271   100
```

Data:

```
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 696435183
set.seed(seed)
a <- replicate(1e3, paste0(sample(0:1, 45, 1, c(0.18, 0.82)), collapse = ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `strsplit` into a `"numeric"` matrix, use `dist`, and finally `which()` with `arr.ind=TRUE`. This is about 80 times faster.

*Example on a vector of length 1e3:*

```
> ## using `adist`
> system.time({
+   ad <- adist(a) |> as.matrix()
+   ares <- which(ad == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  8.642   0.000   8.633 
> 
> ## using `dist`
> system.time({
+   b <- strsplit(a, '') |> do.call(what='rbind') |> `mode<-`('numeric')
+   bd <- dist(b) |> as.matrix()
+   bres <- which(bd == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.098   0.011   0.109 
> 
> stopifnot(all.equal(ares, bres, check.attributes=FALSE))
> 
> head(bres)
    row col
342 342   4
475 475  29
587 587  62
373 373 131
650 650 156
710 710 174
```

Let's view a random result.

```
> set.seed(42)
> a[bres[sample.int(nrow(bres), 1L), ]] |> as.data.frame()
          a[bres[sample.int(nrow(bres), 1L), ]]
1 101111011111110111111111111111111111111111111
2 101111011111110111111111111111111111101111111
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
> a <- replicate(1e3, sample(0:1, 45, replace=TRUE, prob=c(6, 39)) |> 
+                  paste(collapse=''))
```

Comment: new things to learn from this approach

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right this might help

If these are your tests

```
set.seed(42)
stud_tests1 <- replicate(20, paste(sample(0:1, 45, replace=T), collapse=""))
stud_tests2 <- replicate(20, paste(sample(0:1, 45, replace=T), collapse=""))

stud_tests2[6] <- "010010110110101001110110111010110111110110011"
```

Getting the tests that only differ by one

```
one <- strsplit(stud_tests1, "")
two <- strsplit(stud_tests2, "")

res <- sapply(one, \(x) sapply(two, \(y) sum(x != y) == 1))
```

Getting the test numbers

```
cbind(one = ceiling(which(res) / length(one)), two = which(res) %% length(two))
     one two
[1,]  18   6
```